# Verifying Qunit's results with Zombie.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, qunit, zombie.js

I am doing test-driven development with [`Qunit`](http://qunitjs.com/): when creating a new function, I write tests for it, create the function, reload the page, and if all the tests pass I move on... Whilst this works fine at the beginning, it starts to become a time consuming process after a while as all the tests take several seconds to run, and that's the time I have to wait for every time I refresh my browser.

In an attempt to workaround that problem, I thought about introducing [`Zombie.js`](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) to perform head-less testing: the idea is to have `Zombie.js` continuously check the webpage (e.g. `$ watch -n1 "node queryTheWebpage.js"`) and report to me `Qunits`'s results while coding (once in a while, as `Zombie.js` isn't a "real" browser, I would open up a browser and check the page manually to validate).

So far here is what I have for my node/Zombie piece of code:

```
browser.visit("http://localhost/mywebpage.html", function () {
        var qunit_tests = browser.query('body');
        console.log(qunit_tests.innerHTML);
});
```

In the console output I do see the `Qunit` tests container `<ol id="qunit-tests"></ol>` but it is empty which means when the `visit` callback function is called, the tests haven't run.

I've tried to use the `wait` function to wait for the tests to run, but unsuccessfully:

```
function waitForQunitToEnd(window) {
    var last = window.document.querySelector('selectorOfMyLastTest');
    var first_failed = window.document.querySelector('li.failed');
    return (last || first_failed);
}

browser.visit("http://localhost/mywebpage.html", function () {
    browser.wait(waitForQunitToEnd, function() {
        var qunit_tests = browser.query('body');
        console.log(qunit_tests.innerHTML); // still gives me empty <ol id="qunit-tests"></ol>
    });    
});
```

I tried to play with the `waitFor` option (e.g. set to `5000`ms) but that didn't help either.

**Q1: Is what I'm trying to do making sense, or is there a much simpler way of doing something similar?**

**Q2: Do you know how I could get Zombie.js to wait for the Qunit tests to run?**

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution for this?

Comment: I gave up with `Zombie` and am now using `Phantomjs`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498308/how-to-choose-between-zombie-js-and-phantomjs-for-automated-web-testing, https://gist.github.com/gmarik/1305062

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help you but look this : http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.done/